# How to configure django-compressor and django-staticfiles with Amazon's S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

I'm trying to setup [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/) and [django-staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) so that the compressed CSS/Javascript and images are served from Amazon's S3.

I've managed to setup staticfiles using S3 as the backend so it's `collectstatic` command sends the files to S3 instead of `STATIC_ROOT`.

However when trying to add `django-compressor` to the mix is where it all seems to fall apart for me. Following the [documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django_compressor/en/latest/remote-storages/) on setting up remote storages I've created a subclass of the storage backend, [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/), so I copied the [example](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django_compressor/en/latest/remote-storages/#using-staticfiles) to `storage.py`. Once I start using this cached backend the files are copied into static_media and not S3. After the first page load the CACHE folder appears on S3 and in the static_media folder.

Setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and `COMPRESS_STORAGE` back to boto's normal S3 class (`storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`) results in the static assets being collected into the S3 bucket and no static_media folder. However trying to reload the page throws the error:

```
Caught NotImplementedError while rendering: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
```

highlighting `{% compress css %}` as the tag and `compressor/base.py` as the origin.

The s3/staticfiles/compressor section of my `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ='secret'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'
S3_URL = 'http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'client_media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_media'
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = S3_URL + 'admin/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    join(DIRNAME, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_URL = S3_URL
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = COMPRESS_STORAGE
```

So where am I going wrong? Have I mis-configured something when using the `CachedS3BotoStorage` custom storage maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your settings look correct. You should keep both `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and `COMPRESS_STORAGE` set to `storage.CachedS3BotoStorage` though and not switch back to `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`.

According to [this](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/112) django-compressor issue, the problem is with the way django-staticfiles saves during the collectstatic process (using `shutil.copy2`). This issue has been corrected in the newer version of [django-staticfiles](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles/1.1.2), which can be used instead of the one that ships with Django 1.3.

```
pip install django-staticfiles==dev
```

And in your `settings.py`, switch to the updated version:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    #"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    #"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'staticfiles',
    #...
)
```

After running `python manage.py collectstatic` again, both the CACHE directory from django-compressor and the collected staticfiles files should show up on S3.

Answer (score 0):

Using `django_compressor==1.2` worked for me. I am not sure why you need to install django-staticfiles however all the versions of `django_compressor` except 1.2 has that issue.

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of days of hard work and research I was finally able to do this and I decided to write a [detailed guide](http://condopilot.com/blog/web/how-setup-gzip-compressor-and-aws-s3-django/) about it, including how to also serve them zipped with gzip.

Basically you need to do a few things:

1. Use `AWS_IS_GZIPPED = True`
2. If your S3 is outside of US. You need to create a custom `S3Connection` class where you override the `DefaultHost` variable to your S3 url. Example `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`
3. If you're using a dotted bucket name, example `subdomain.domain.tld`. You need to set `AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'`
4. You have to set `non_gzipped_file_content = content.file` in your `CachedS3BotoStorage`

This is the `CachedS3BotoStorage` class you need:

```
class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    connection_class = EUConnection
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

def save(self, name, content):
    non_gzipped_file_content = content.file
    name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
    content.file = non_gzipped_file_content
    self.local_storage._save(name, content)
    return name
```

Note that `EUConnection` is a custom class where I set `DefaultHost` to my S3 location. Check the much longer and detailed guide for complete custom storages and settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Try this post that complete the above solution with some lines, to fix the problem that create many (multiples) manifest_%.json in Amazon S3.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31545361/1359475