# Django-Compressor throws UncompressableFileError with django-storages using amazonaws and heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-storage, django-compressor

I am having problem to locate the issue of the problem.

I have settings folder and inside I have local.py, common.py and production.py. All is working great and it is compressing on localhost, but not on heroku.

When I deploy it I am getting error:

```
Internal Server Error: /

UncompressableFileError at /
'https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/stylesheet.css' isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('//xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/static/') and can't be compressed
```

common.py

```
# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('staticfiles'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static')),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

# MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {
    'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL,
    'MEDIA_URL': MEDIA_URL,
}

COMPRESS_ENABLED=True
```

production.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = OrdinaryCallingFormat()


# AWS cache settings, don't change unless you know what you're doing:
AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

# TODO See: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/47
# Revert the following and use str after the above-mentioned bug is fixed in
# either django-storage-redux or boto
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': six.b('max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (
        AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY))
}

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT, used for managing
# stored files.
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "//%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)


# Static Assests
# ------------------------
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStaticStorage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStaticStorage'

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "//%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)


# See: https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast
# For Django 1.7+, 'collectfast' should come before
# 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
INSTALLED_APPS = ['collectfast', ] + INSTALLED_APPS
```

custom_storages.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class


class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = True


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False


class CachedS3BotoStaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """
    location = 'static'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStaticStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent the whole night trying to solve this and I made a little change in this code:

```
isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('//xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/static/')
```

I thought it can add http or https and I have

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True
```

So just for test I added hardcoded

```
https:
```

like this

```
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

and it started working, it is great. But can anyone explain why it is not recognizing or adding http or https to it?

Comment: The templatetag `{% static %}` is replaced by the exact test set in `STATIC_URL`. If you write say, "testdomain.com" it'll go to "http://localhost:8000/testdomain.com/static/whateverfile". That's simply browser behavior. What you want is "//testdomain.com". That tells the browser to replace "//" with "http://" if the website you're on is HTTP and "https://" if it's got SSL on.